# Eclipse lombok errors

Tags: eclipse, lombok

I'm getting this error message:

[image]

Message is:

> edu cannot be resolved to a type

I've added `lombok.jar` into `eclipse` folder and it's detected:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the whole project? If that doesn't help, please add your lombok.config to your question.

Comment: I've refreshed root gradle project and error have been clean up. Why did you suggest it?

Comment: Because something like `edu` is nowhere in your class, and Lombok does not generate anything named `edu`. So it was likely a remainder of something old.

Answer (score 4):

Mostly likely your lombok.config contains the following line:

```
lombok.extern.findbugs.addSuppressFBWarnings=true
```

The SuppressFBWarnings annotation is located in **edu**.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations, which is why you are getting that error.

Make sure findbugs is on the classpath as mentioned in the [documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/configuration):

> Lombok can add the @SuppressFBWarnings annotation which is useful if
>   you want to run FindBugs on your class files. To enable this feature,
>   make sure findbugs is on the classpath when you compile,

It seems you are using gradle, so adding the following should work:

```
compile group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', name: 'annotations', version: '3.0.1'
```

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.findbugs/annotations/3.0.1#gradle

Comment: Adding :
implementation 'com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs-annotations:4.8.1'
to the build.gradle file worked for me.
Thank you very much.